# Is it possible to "reverse" a remote computer access session?

Tags: networking, batch, remote-access

For example: I want to bait a scammer into accessing my throw-away computer, then flip the connection around so that I'm now accessing THEIR computer so I can wreck their scamming operations.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible under normal circumstances.

The reason for this is that if you let them authenticate against your computer - you give them access to it.. not the other way around.

For instance, if you gave me your car keys, that doesn't mean in any way that you could drive my car.

In theory, you could bait your PC with some malware which woud then open up their PC for you to exploit, but this is a very long-winded and tricky process that is not covered by the question scope on this site.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other answers you need authentication from that PC and user to connect to it. by giving your authentication to him the active remote desktop session is on your PC not theirs. It would be best to infect your throw away computer with a nasty dropper virus and save it into a file called "Bank Details" or something revealing like that. it would be similar to the prevention of hacking a PS3 system that my friend used which uses a safely contained Computer virus in a file that when it is opened it malfunctions the hacking PS3 to a point where it will break the console.

If the scammer is using software to help him gain control of your files and the like it would be best to find a virus that can also destroy or scramble files on their PC I would suggest a cryptlocker... although it would be very risky to tamper with such a volatile virus and fighting fire with fire in this case? wouldn't that bring you down to their level. It may also be beneficial to find a way of blocking this scammer instead of trying to scam him back. Negligence usually would annoy a scammer/hacker a lot more than a direct attack. Its a matter of tolerance and being secure.

Furthermore if you interact with the scammer and they are caught by authorities, even a trace of your interaction with their files and folders would implement you in the acts they are carrying out. So be very careful with what you try to do to one up an internet fraudster/scammer/terrorist whatever you want to call them.